# What are the two qubits in the state $a\lvert 00\rangle+b\lvert11\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

What are the $2$ qubits of the state
$a\lvert 00\rangle+b\lvert11\rangle$?

Are they $a'\vert0\rangle+b'\vert1\rangle$ and $c'\vert0\rangle+d'\vert1\rangle$?

How are they measured, and what would be the outcome on each qubit?

Comment: The qubits are the leftmost qubit and the rightmost qubit.  They are entangled; when you measure them in the computational (assuming your normalization factor is $1/\sqrt2$) you either get $00$ or $11$.  The left qubit is $0$ or $1$, and the right qubit is the same as the left qubit (it will be measured to be the same value).

Comment: When you say the left qubit is 0 or 1 you mean |0⟩+|1⟩ ? measurement of the last qubit |0⟩+|1⟩ could be either 0 or 1 so it's not the same value as you stated

Comment: as far as i know there's no qubit 0 or 1 but |0⟩ or |1⟩

Comment: If you want to take the *left* qubit and send it to Mars, and the *right* qubit and send it to Jupiter, they would respectively be in the (mixed) *state* of your edit.  To me, a qubit is something *physical*, however.  It's like saying a (classical) *bit* corresponds to a voltage on a wire, with a *value* of either $0$ or $1$, while a *qubit* corresponds to a spin, with a *state* being $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(\vert 0\rangle+\vert 1\rangle)$.

Comment: As soon as you *measure* the qubit, you "collapse" the value to a classical bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't associate some pure states $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ to the subsystems of the 2-qubit system in the entangled state ($a\vert 00\rangle+b\vert11\rangle, a\ne 0, b \ne 0$ in our case). This is the definition of entanglement. You can verify that there is no vectors $|x\rangle$, $|y\rangle$ such that $|x\rangle \otimes |y\rangle = a\vert 0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle+b\vert1\rangle \otimes |1\rangle$.

But we can associate mixed states to the subsystems of this entangled state. Mixed state is a probability distribution over pure states. Both mixed states in this case coincide and equal to $\{ |0\rangle$ with probability $|a|^2$, $|1\rangle$ with probability $|b|^2\}$.

The general method of calculating (mixed) state of a subsystem is via partial trace of density matrix.

In our case 
$$\text{tr}_1((a|00\rangle + b|11\rangle)(\bar{a}\langle 00| + \bar{b}\langle11|)) = 
|a^2|\cdot |0\rangle\langle0| + |b^2| \cdot |1\rangle\langle1|
$$

So the density matrix of the second qubit is $|a^2|\cdot |0\rangle\langle0| + |b^2| \cdot |1\rangle\langle1|$.
Similarly for the 1st qubit.